# char pointer return issue

Tags: c, pointers

I have a problem with my c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    void main()
    {
        char* testVal = getCharValue();
        printf("testVal : %s\n",testVal); //testVal = (null) why?
    }

    char* getCharValue()
    {
        char *text;

        setCharValue(text);

        return text;
    }

    void setCharValue(char* str)
    {
        char *a1 = "hello";

        strcpy(str,a1); //error ?
    }
```

I need to return `char` pointer value. But this code doesn't return the value. Why?

Comment: _//error ?_ Is there an error, or not?

Comment: You are using an uninitialized pointer as the destination address for `strcpy`.  Your program has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Does this make sense to you?

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Function Prototypes
char *getCharValue();
void setCharValue(char *str);

// main()
int main(void)
{
    char* testVal;
    testVal = getCharValue();
    puts(testVal);
    //printf("testVal : %s\n", *testVal); //testVal = (null) why?
    return 0;
}

// Function Definitions
char *getCharValue()
{
    char *text;
    if( (text = (char *)calloc(1, 10)) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory Unavailable.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    setCharValue(text);
    return text;
}

void setCharValue(char* str)
{
    char *a1 = "Hello";
    strcpy(str, a1); //error ?
}
```

All used `char` pointers in this program will just point to a character except `a1`. Because `a1` is a `char *`, a `char array` and name of that `char array`. So, you can just point to this.

Like this `testVal<->getcharValue()->setCharValue(text)->a1`.

You are altering the value stored at `text` using its address in `setCharValue()`. Then you are returning address of `text` from `getCharValue()` to the invoker `main()`. In `main()`, address returned by `getCharValue()` is assigned to `testVal`. So, `testVal` has just an address which is of type `char *`.

If you put `printf("testVal : %c\n", *testVal);` you can verify this.
So, in order to print character stored at that address and furthermore characters from that address, you should use `puts()` function.

I hope it helps you to understand pointers in C and how they work.

Comment: `text` will not point to anything. `text` is not assigned any value. Copying a string via `strcpy` does not make the pointer point to the source. The stringliteral will be copied to the address where `text` points to which is unfortunately an unspecified address.

Comment: The address of `text` is not returned anywhere. The value of `text` is return which is the address where `text` points to. That is a difference and you shoud take care about correct wording.

Comment: The assignment in your comment is even worse. You suggest to change a local copy `str` which will not have any effect after that function is left. Just assigning the address of that string literal will also make the pointer point to some immutable memory address which might be unexpected as the return type of `getCharValue` is `char*` and not `const char*` . The caller will not be able to change the content.

Comment: Why not provide valid memory to `text` and keep everything else as is?

Comment: How would you know what the OP is trying? He is trying to copy some content to a string buffer. Perfectly fine except for uninitialized pointer issue.

Comment: "It seems to work" is exaclty what makes undefined behaviour hard to find in many cases

Comment: Yeah! this ```undefined behaviour``` word always catches me everywhere. But I never find any of 'em.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215347/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-lucas).

Answer (score 0):

hello Lucas and Gerhardh.. thanks for help.

my solution is

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

    void main()
    {
        char* testVal = getCharValue();
        printf("testVal : %s\n",testVal); //testVal = (null) why?
    }

    char* getCharValue()
    {
        char *text="hello";

        strcpy(str, text);

        return text;
    }
```

my problem is work out. this code